# Regex for API subdomains

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to have a regex that matches the following domains:

- dev.api.company.com
- live.api.company.com
- test1.dev-api.company.com
- test2.live-api.company.com
- yyy.XXXapi.company.com

But does not match on the followings:

- dev-api.company.com
- live-api.company.com
- api.company.com
- XXXapi.company.com

I have tried this: ^[a-z]+.[a-z-]*api.company.com$ but it not working, and I can not make it work. Can you help me please?

I am using javascript String.match() function.

Comment: So, the formula is that first string before dot shouldn't have a hyphen?

Comment: @gurvinder372 yeah, but `api.company.com` shouldn't match either... so

Comment: So there should be 3 sub-domains, not 2?

Comment: no, it can have. I can be d-ev.api.company.com but can not be d-ev-api.company.com there like X.Xapi.company.com but not Xapi.company.com X can be anything.

Comment: Ok, but can you describe the formule you are looking for?

Comment: Is the formula, "(1) must end with the string `api.company.com`, and (2) the left-most subdomain part cannot be hyphenated or the exact string `api`"?

Comment: @apsillers I updated the list. The point is I need one more level before .[somethingOrNothing]api.company.com

Comment: What I understand, you only want 4th level domains and reject everything else. e.g  you want `live.api.company.com` but not `api.company.com`

Comment: Do you tolerate *more* than four levels? Or only exactly four?

Comment: @apsillers no, it can not be more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\.]*api\.company\.com$
```

**[Demo](http://regexr.com/3cv0e)**

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
if (string.matches("^(dev\\.api|live\\.api|test\\d+)\\..*$")) {
    // Accepted subdomain
} else {
    // Nope
}
```

You can enter as many options as you want, separating them with |

Breakup of the regex:

^ - starts with

(option1|option2|option3) - a list of accepted subdomains

\. - a subdomain must be followed by a period

.*$ anything else until the end of the string

This solution allows you to administer the accepted subdomains easily if you don't have a general rule of thumb for selection.

Comment: Thank you, but dev and live are just example. they can be anyhting. not just dev or live it should match devxxx.api.company.com too. But not on devxxx-api.company.com

Comment: without a rule for the accepted domains, we can't realy make a rule to select anything...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^[a-z\\.\\-]{0,}api.company.com$/
```

Tests against your examples and it works.

Comment: this also accepts the subdomains asked to be ignored.